# RIchtextbox in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am building an application for windows phone 7 where i have a few data coming from the web service. Those fields are:

```
restaurant_name, street_address, location_name, country, phone_no, email_id
```

Now as there will be multiple rows of data, will it be possible if i take a single richtextbox control and display the data in it. As i will display one row of data when the user swipes the textbox the next row should be shown. Please someone give me some idea for solving this issue. I am not asking for any codes just help me with some idea so that i can start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to bind the rows to a ListBox, and set the ItemTemplate of the ListBox to a DataTemplate containing a RichTextBox displaying one item.

Comment: How can it be done? Can u please provide codes if i send mine

Comment: Actually i have never used richtextbox so will be thankful if u can help

Comment: Start by reading up on XAML (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc189036(v=vs.105).aspx), data binding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx) and the various controls, you'll need it if you want to get anywhere.